# Simple lookup query very slow on Postgres, fast in MySQL

Tags: postgresql, pentaho

I'm beating my head on this since yesterday, and I don't understanf what's happening:

I am populating a dimensional schema for a datawarehousing project, using Pentaho Kettle to perform a "dimension lookup/update", which basically looks up for existing rows in a dimension table, inserting the ones which do not exist and returning the technical key.

The dimension table itself is very simple:

```
CREATE TABLE dim_loan
(
    _tech_id INTEGER NOT NULL,

    loan_id INTEGER,
    type TEXT,
    interest_rate_type TEXT,

    _dim_project_id integer,

    _validity_from date,
    _validity_to date,
    _version integer,

    PRIMARY KEY (_tech_id)
);
CREATE INDEX dim_loan_pk_idx ON dim_loan USING btree (_tech_id);
CREATE INDEX dim_loan_compound_idx ON dim_loan USING btree (loan_id, _dim_project_id, _validity_from, _validity_to);
```

The table should contain, at the end of the process, around 650k rows. The transformations starts fast(ish), at around 1500 rows/sec.
The performance drops steadily reaching 50 rows/sec by the time the table has around 50k rows.
The queries that Kettle does look like this:

```
SELECT _tech_id, _version, "type" AS "Loan Type", interest_rate_type AS int_rate, _validity_from, _validity_to FROM "public".dim_loan WHERE loan_id = $1  AND _dim_project_id = $2  AND $3 >= _validity_from AND $4 < _validity_to
```

The query planner estimates an execution time of 0.1 msecs:

```
"Index Scan using dim_loan_compound_idx on dim_loan  (cost=0.42..7.97 rows=1 width=42) (actual time=0.043..0.043 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  Index Cond: ((loan_id = 1) AND (_dim_project_id = 2) AND ('2016-01-01'::date >= _validity_from) AND ('2016-01-01'::date < _validity_to))"
"Total runtime: 0.078 ms"
```

Of course real execution times are much different, around 10ms, which is unacceptable. Enabling slow query log with auto_explain I see with increased frequency entries like this:

```
Seq Scan on dim_loan  (cost=0.00..2354.21 rows=12 width=52)
          Filter: (($3 >= _validity_from) AND ($4 < _validity_to) AND (_dim_project_id = $2) AND ((loan_id)::double precision = $1))
< 2016-12-18 21:30:19.859 CET >LOG:  duration: 14.260 ms  plan:
        Query Text: SELECT _tech_id, _version, "type" AS "Loan Type", interest_rate_type AS int_rate, _validity_from, _validity_to FROM "public".dim_loan WHERE loan_id = $1  AND _dim_project_id = $2  AND $3 >= _validity_from
         AND $4 < _validity_to
```

Which don't tell the whole story anyway as it's not only these queries that run slow, but all of them.
Of course I tried to tweak the memory parameters up to silly amounts with no real difference in performance, I also tried the latest 9.6, which exhibited the same behavior as 9.3, which is what I'm using.

The same transformation, on a MySQL database with the same indexes, runs happily at 5000 rows/sec from start to finish. I really want to use PG and I'm sure that it's something trivial, but what!?
Maybe something with the jdbc driver? I verified that it does use a single connection all the time, so it's not even a connection overhead issue...

Comment: Why is `loan_id` being cast to double precision?

Comment: spot on Richard, thanks!

Comment: The output of `explain analyze` is **not** an "estimated" execution time. It is the **actual** execution time the query took **on the server** - without sending the results to the client. If `explain analyze` says 0.078ms and you measure 10ms on the client side, the difference is the time it takes to send the data (although that is a bit surprising with zero rows returned)

Answer (score 2):

Just found out that the cause is indeed loan id being cast to double, which of course rendered the index useless! The reason is a wrong assumption made by Kettle on the metadata of this column, which comes from an excel file.
Now the performance is on par with MySQL! Happy days